# Transform <td> content to String in Python 3 using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So, I have this:

```
<td>MBC: <b>0.01 €</b>   EBC: <b>0.01 €</b>   SC: <b>0.25 €</b>   </td>
```

And I want a string that looks something like this:

MBS: 0.01€, EBC:0.01€, SC:0.25€

How can I  take the MBC, EBC and SC out of the ?

Thanks!

Comment: search for beautifulsoup get text tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
text = soup.get_text()
print(text)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_text](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method on an element: It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag

```
[ x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.find_all('td')][index of desire td] # here put your td index.
```